# Save image url path in DB columns

Tags: php, database, image, imageurl

i am updating name , email in DB of registered user through php form. its working fine.

**class.usr.php**

```
public function update($uname,$email, $tax)
    {
    try {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET userName = ?, userEmail = ? , tax = ?  WHERE userID = ? ');
    $stmt->execute(array($uname,$email, $tax , $_SESSION['userSession']));
    return $stmt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
```

**form**

```
<form action="profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Name : 
<input type="text" name="txtuname" value="<?php echo $row['userName'] ?>" /><br/>
Email :
<input type="text" name="txtemail" value="<?php echo $row['userEmail'] ?>" /><br>
Image
<input type="file" name="photo" id="fileSelect"><br> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

**form related code to save in db**

```
<?php

$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: index.php");
die();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$tax = trim($_POST['tax']); // image url path

$uid = (isset($_SESSION['userSession']) ? intval($_SESSION['userSession']) : 0);

if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $tax, $uid))
{
    header("Location: profile1.php");
   die(); 
}
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

after this, now i am uploading an image to folder through same php form successfully with below code.

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_FILES["photo"]["error"])){ 
if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0){ 
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>"; 

} else{ 
$allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png"); 
$filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
$filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"]; 
$filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"]; 

// Verify file extension 
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format."); 

// Verify file size - 5MB maximum 
$maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit."); 

// Verify MYME type of the file 
if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){ 
// Check whether file exists before uploading it 
if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){ 
echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " is already exists."; 

} else{ 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]); 

echo "Your file was uploaded successfully."; 
} 
} else{ 

echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again."; 
} 

} 

} else{ 
echo ""; 
} 

?>
```

now images are just saving in folders, what i need is **i want that image path to save in database and assign that image path to uploaded user in database.** so that one registered user can update the existing image, but not upload one more image.

i tried below code , but not working:

```
<?php
$folder = "upload/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    $tax= $full_path;

    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){ 
// Check whether file exists before uploading it 
if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){ 
echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " is already exists."; 

} else{ 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]); 

echo "Your file was uploaded successfully."; 
} 
} else{ 

echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again."; 
} 

} 

} else{ 
echo ""; 
} 
?>
```

**db columns** : userName, userEmail, tax , photo

with help of google i done all above, i am new to php, so please kindly help me.

Comment: both image and db codes are same. *Update needed*

Comment: @Thamilan updated the code, Thanks for informing.....

Comment: You are asking us to write code for you! We fix your attempts at coding we do not write brand new code for you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your comment, i tried some code as i posted in question, but it did't worked for me....

Comment: Yes, but I see no attempt at updating the user photo information

Comment: @RiggsFolly firstly i am trying to save image path in db column, than i will try to display image.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new function for saving files and use global php var `$_FILES`

**1**
Add new column to your DB to store file path, let's name it `photo`

**2**
Add new functions for your user class:

```
<?php
class User {
...
  const PATH_PHOTOS = '/path/to/photo/folder/';
  const BASE_URL = 'http://YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME:YOUR_PORT/YOUR_PATH/';

  public function add_photo($file)
  {
    $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file['new_name'] = uniqid(rand(), true) . ".$ext";
    if (!$this->_upload_file($file))
      return false;
    return $this->_remove_previous_photo()->_add_file_to_db(self::PATH_PHOTOS .     basename($file['new_name']));
  }

  protected function _remove_previous_photo()
  {
    $photo = $this->get_photo();
    if ($photo)
      unlink($photo);
    return $this;
  }

  public function get_photo()
  {
    global $_SESSION;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT photo FROM tbl_users WHERE userID = ?     ');
    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['userSession']));
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    return reset($result);
  }

  public function get_photo_url()
  {
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($this->get_photo());
    $last_dir = end(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathInfo['dirname']));
    return self::BASE_URL . "$last_dir/" . basename($this->get_photo());
  }

  protected function _upload_file($file)
  {
    $uploadfile = self::PATH_PHOTOS . $file['new_name'];
    return move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
  }

  protected function _add_file_to_db($file_path)
  {
    try {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET photo = ? WHERE userID = ? ');
      return $stmt->execute(array($file_path, $_SESSION['userSession']));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
    }
  }
...
}
?>
```

**3**
The main file should look like this:

```
<?php

$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: index.php");
die();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$tax = trim($_POST['tax']); // image url path

$uid = (isset($_SESSION['userSession']) ? intval($_SESSION['userSession']) : 0);

if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $tax, $uid) && $user_home->add_photo($_FILES['photo']))
{
    header("Location: profile1.php");
   die(); 
}
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry, its not working for me , i gave path as [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site3/upload/)

Comment: still not working, looks like i am missing somewhere, can you please check these codes : class.user.php : http://pastebin.com/Zkue3Tyn ,  main file : http://pasted.co/2e0a4c65

Comment: I have checked the file you gave me. The constant PATH_PHOTOS - is not a URL it should be a pass on a server

Comment: can you please give me updated code for that.....

Comment: I am not sure where the files are located on your server, but there definatelly should be a directory where theese files should be stored(the permissions should include read/write for images, but no execute for security reasons). When you setup the directory on your server make sure it's accessible by your apache(for linux systems open terminal and type ```su -www -s /sh/bin``` go to the folder you created and try to get any file). After change the PATH_PHOTOS to absolute path on your server

Comment: the images are uploading fine in folders, but the image paths are not saving in database.....

Comment: okay, i changed the path to `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site3/upload` , here only all uploaded images are storing, but the file path is not saving in database column `photo`

Comment: I've updated the code, i suppose the $_SESSION var was not taken as it was in global scope. Try it now

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

First of all execute this query manually to add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_users` ADD `photo` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ;
```

Then this is the php code:

```
<?php
$dbConn = new Database();
$dbConn->dbConnection();

$user_home = new USER();

function uploadUserPhoto($uid) {
    global $dbConn;
    if(isset($_FILES["photo"]["error"])) {
        if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>";

        } else {
            $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
            $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
            $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];

            $userDir = $uid;

            // Verify file extension
            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

            // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
            $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

            // Verify MYME type of the file
            if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)) {
                if(!is_dir('upload/'.$uid)) {
                    mkdir('upload/'.$uid);
                }

                $photoname = time().$uid.'_photo'.'.'.$ext;

                // delete all the files in this directory
                $files = glob('upload/'.$uid.'/*'); // get all file names
                foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
                    if(is_file($file))
                        unlink($file); // delete file
                }

                // Upload the photo
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $uid . '/'. $photoname);

                $updateData = array(':userID' => $uid, ':photo' => $photoname);
                $stmt = $dbConn->conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET photo=:photo WHERE userID=:uid");
                $stmt->execute($updateData);

                echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
            } else {
                echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
}

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // new data
    $uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
    $email = $_POST['txtemail'];
    $tax = trim($_POST['tax']); // image url path

    $uid = (isset($_SESSION['userSession']) ? intval($_SESSION['userSession']) : 0);

    if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $tax, $uid))
    {
        uploadUserPhoto($uid);
        header("Location: profile1.php");
        die();
    }
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

There is `$dbConnection` variable which is the connection to the DB but because I don't know the rest of your code you should replace it with your proper db connection variable.

The photo of the user is saved in `photo` column in `tbl_users` and for every user is created sub dir in `uploads` dir. The subdir is the userID. So for example for user with `userID = 1` its upload path will be `uploads/1/<filename>`.

File name is generated dynamically - this avoids caching of uploaded photo with the same name for example ... and it is better approach.

You have to make a change in code for displaying the photo because now its filename is in the DB and there is subdir in uploads (which is the userID of the user)

Comment: can you please tell me what code  i need to change for `displaying the photo`

Comment: Add your code for displaying image here

Comment: i need to save the image path in db column, thats also not working for me , can you please join here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126594/discussion-between-abcd-and-krasipenkov

Comment: db file : http://pastebin.com/LKtgBnUF, i followed your answer properly, but still where i am missing ?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: sorry, i updated your code, still image-paths are not displaying under columns, please check these codes : class.usr.php : http://pastebin.com/iLVbMAfN , profile.php : http://pastebin.com/tmVj80jh

Comment: please download complete files : https://ufile.io/58d11 & db file : https://uploadfiles.io/2128

Comment: Here is the corrected code: https://ufile.io/01f9 I also added db changes directly in dbtest.sql. Code changes are not that much.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help, i used same files and db that you pasted in above links, but once i browse and select image, its not uploading to folder , also path also not displaying in db. its displaying like this link : http://prnt.sc/cz17ot

Comment: when  i inspect element on that, i found that sub-folder created under `upload` folder is showing : http://prnt.sc/cz1c75 , `subfolder:22` is the `user_id` of that user......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126691/discussion-between-abcd-and-krasipenkov).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your all support, i found solution, need your help like this in upcoming days also .... i am sorry that i wasted your lot of time.....